# Changing QColor in QT c++

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function that changes the colour of a selected shape using:

`selectedShape->shapeColour = (200,200,200);`

which works fine. But if I change it to:

`selectedShape->shapeColour = (0,0,0);`

I get the following error:

> conversion from 'int' to 'const QColor' is ambigous

Any ideas why it doesn't like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
selectedShape->shapeColour = QColor(0,0,0);
```

with `C++11` you can also try:

```
selectedShape->shapeColour = {0,0,0};
```

Comment: Thats what I would suggest. Frankly, I am surprised that `selectedShape->shapeColour = (200,200,200);` even works...

Answer (score 6):

Your `(200,200,200)` is evaluated, using the comma operator, as an integer with value 200.

This satisfies the `QColor( QRgb color )` constructor since `QRgb` is a typedef for an unsigned integer.

This is different to the `(0,0,0)` case, which evaluates as 0, because 0 could also be interpreted as a null pointer.

In your context, this causes an ambiguity as QColor also has a constructor which takes a pointer `QColor( const char * name )`.

The compiler can't tell which construction you were intending and so gives you the error about it being ambiguous.

You can resolve this using -

```
selectedShape->shapeColour = QColor(0,0,0);
```

If you want the colors you are intending, I'd suggest that you use this approach for your (200,200,200) case too -

```
selectedShape->shapeColour = QColor(200,200,200);
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining why `(200,200,200)` was even valid. Completely forgot that the `,` operator could be used in that manner.